# Can we make the Worklight console accessible only via an internal network

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, worklight-console

We are working with a client who is interested in having the Worklight Console app only accessible from an internal network.  They are currently running Worklight on a Liberty server.  Is it possible to have the Worklight console listen on a different port or different IP than the deployed Worklight apps (project war files)?  If so, are there any docs on what would need to be modified (eg. server.xml, database, etc)?  Thanks!

JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit access to Worklight Console you could change the console's port number as defined in the application server's server.xml file.

You could then limit access to that port (and possibly the context root used as well) from external traffic using the corporate firewall  system or otherwise.

Because you did not mention your Worklight version:

- If using v5.0.0.x - v6.1.0.x, you'll need to make sure you block only requests going to the console and not all runtime requests (because the console and the runtime share the same context root)
- If using v6.2.0.x, the console has its own context root so less worries there

Comment: Thanks, we are using 6.2  I wasn't sure if we needed to make any additional changes (analytics, db, etc)